# Publish the same application with two different ids

Tags: android

I have an app that I want to distribute on Google Play, this app will be uploaded with an X company account, while, I would like to upload it to my developer account to do upload tests. If I change packageName and sign it with another key, then I can upload it with the real credentials and the official keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play store requires each app to have a unique package-name to identify each app individually.

You can publish the same app in different account with a different package name and `keystore` , Package name + signature combo must be unique .

But if you app are using some generated `api key` based on the **package name** or **`SHA`** , you should use the correct `api key` accordingly to package or `keystore` to keep the app working in both account